# Inject field into JSON response object

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, jackson2

I'd like to inject a field into the response object during serialization. Is it possible to inject "success": "true" into the JSON response object? This needs to be a general solution for all parent response objects that are serialized.

For example with object:

```
public class UserResponse {
    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Organisation organisation;

    // getters setters
}
```

Jackson should return:

```
{
    "success": "true",
    "id": 1, 
    "firstName": "tom",
    "lastName": "jeffrey",
    "organisation": {
        // etc.
    }
}
```

I tried already with

```
public class CustomJsonSerializer extends StdSerializer<Object> {

    public CustomJsonSerializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    public CustomJsonSerializer(Class<Object> t) {
        super(t);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Object o, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
        jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
        jsonGenerator.writeStringField("success", "true");
        jsonGenerator.writeObject(o);
        jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

But didn't succeed:

```
Could not write JSON: Can not start an object, expecting field name (context: Object); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerationException: Can not start an object, expecting field name (context: Object)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `ResponseBodyAdvice` to modify the object returned by a controller before being serialized into JSON. Here is a trivial example which is applied by default to all responses:

The view your controller returns

```
public class Greeting {
    private static final String message = "Hello World!";

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

The response wrapper for setting a status

```
public class ResponseWrapper {
    private Object data;
    private boolean success;

    public Object getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Object data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public boolean isSuccess() {
        return success;
    }

    public void setSuccess(boolean success) {
        this.success = success;
    }
}
```

The controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/hello")
public class HelloController {
    @GetMapping
    public Greeting hello() {
        return new Greeting();
    }
}
```

Test that validates the behavior

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest
public class HelloControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    private static final String GREETING_ENDPOINT = "/api/hello";


    @Test
    public void returnsGreetingWithStatus() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get(GREETING_ENDPOINT))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.data.message").value("Hello World!"))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.success").value(true));
    }
}
```

The **ResponseBodyAdvice**

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ResponseStatusAdvice implements ResponseBodyAdvice {
    @Override
    public boolean supports(MethodParameter returnType, Class converterType) {
        return converterType.equals(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Object beforeBodyWrite(Object body, MethodParameter returnType, MediaType selectedContentType, Class selectedConverterType, ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response) {
        ResponseWrapper wrapper = new ResponseWrapper();
        wrapper.setData(body);
        wrapper.setSuccess(true);
        return wrapper;
    }
}
```

This should give you a head start.
On a side note, you can always take advantage of HTTP status codes. It is part of the protocol and will always be set.

Comment: Looks like a very interesting solution. I'm going to try it out now. You're right about the status codes, which is also the best practice. But the javascript framework I'm using requires `success = true` responses for the API callbacks to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you need is a

```
@JsonAppend(attrs = {@JsonAppend.Attr(value = "success")})
public class UserResponse implements Serializable {
  private int id;
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
  private Organisation organisation;

  // getters setters
}
```

Have you looked into it?

Here is an example of how I thought it would be done.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonAppend;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class InjectFieldTest {

  @Test
  public void testResponse() throws JsonProcessingException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    final UserResponse response =
        new UserResponse(1, "Stack", "Overfloww", new Organisation("Developers"));
    final ObjectWriter writer =
        mapper.writerFor(UserResponse.class).withAttribute("success", "true");

    final String out = writer.writeValueAsString(response);
    System.out.println("jsData = " + out);
    Assert.assertTrue(out.contains("success"));
  }

  @JsonAppend(attrs = {@JsonAppend.Attr(value = "success")})
  private class UserResponse implements Serializable {

    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Organisation organisation;

    public UserResponse(int id, String firstName, String lastName, Organisation organisation) {
      this.id = id;
      this.firstName = firstName;
      this.lastName = lastName;
      this.organisation = organisation;
    }

    public int getId() {
      return id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
      return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
      return lastName;
    }

    public Organisation getOrganisation() {
      return organisation;
    }
  }

  private class Organisation {
    private String name;

    public Organisation(String name) {
      this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
      return name;
    }
  }
}
```

Based on your criteria of success, you can set this value to true or false.

Comment: But this requires me to add this to add classes beforehand. I was looking for a way to add this pre-serialization. One solution for all parent response objects

Comment: If parent in your case is the supper class(es) then put it on super class. Tell me why an appropriate http response code is not enough for your rest service?

Comment: It's a JavaScript framework thing that requires `success = true` responses for the API callbacks to work properly.

Comment: It's a working an interesting approach yes. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this can be done during `serialization`. But if you want, you can do slightly modify your `Response` to achieve what you want in generic way:

```
public class ServiceResponse <T>{
  private boolean success;

  //your data which you want to access/use in client side.  You can pass `UserResponse`  or whatever class you want to pass as general.
   private T data;
}
```

Now, set your value to this `class` object,  and `serialize`. You can add `message` string field for custom message if needed.
Now, `ServiceResponse`  will accept for other `classes` too.

Answer (score 0):

Add boolean success to the UserResponse class and set it before searialization.